# How to find out which canidate [Male or Female] scored maximum points in each city?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have this dataframe and I want to find out who secured maximum points in each city.

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame({"City":["Delhi","Delhi","Mumbai","Mumbai","Lahore","Lahore"],
"Points":[90.1,90.3,94.1,95,89,90.5],
"Gender":["Male","Female","Female","Male","Female","Male"]})
```

So far I have tried this, but this is giving me the toppers of both gender[male and female] in each city,

```
df.groupby(by=["City","Gender"],sort=False)["Points"].max()
```

[image: Output:]

I want a single candidate[male or female] who scored maximum points in each city.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one will give you a table of the highest scores only

```py
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "City":["Delhi","Delhi","Mumbai","Mumbai","Lahore","Lahore"],
    "Points":[90.1,90.3,94.1,95,89,90.5],
    "Gender":["Male","Female","Female","Male","Female","Male"]
})

df.groupby('City').apply(lambda x: x.sort_values('Points').tail(1)).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
     City  Points  Gender
0   Delhi    90.3  Female
1  Lahore    90.5    Male
2  Mumbai    95.0    Male
```

Answer (score 1):

try using a pivot table with only 'City' as the index:

```
df.pivot_table(values='Points',index=['City'],aggfunc='max')
```

#Output

```
        Points
City          
Delhi     90.3
Lahore    90.5
Mumbai    95.0
```

If you wanna use groupby, feel free to do that but again, remember to use only 'City' as here, the gender does not matter

```
df.groupby(by=["City"],sort=False)["Points"].max()
#Output
City
Delhi     90.3
Mumbai    95.0
Lahore    90.5
Name: Points, dtype: float64
```

If you want to see the gender also, use this:

```
df.groupby('City').apply(lambda x: x.sort_values('Points').iloc[-1].reset_index(drop=True))
```

Output

```
    0   1   2
City            
Delhi   Delhi   90.3    Female
Lahore  Lahore  90.5    Male
Mumbai  Mumbai  95.0    Male
```

Comment: but it doesn't tell me whether it was a boy or girl who scored maximum in each city

Comment: I edited my original answer and added that also